# Starting selenium chromedriver failed with Chrome60

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Detailed error log as below:

```
TESTFAIL; com.ibm.test.inotes.authentication.LoginTestCase; 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to normal, current state is maximized
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 104 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'inotess-imac.cn.ibm.com', ip: '9.123.154.177', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262), userDataDir=/var/folders/k5/7h9wrl411lscklkysfgpdj3r0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.4Yvm6j}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.113, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 1fad624912a4ca9ed46ea749eef0521c
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:6
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.setSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:891)
at appobjects.web.Browser.setSize(Browser.java:420)
at appobjects.web.Browser.maximize(Browser.java:520)
at com.ibm.test.inotes.iNotesTestCase.testSetUp(iNotesTestCase.java:626)
at com.ibm.test.BaseTestCase.before(BaseTestCase.java:30)
at com.ibm.test.inotes.iNotesTestSuiteRunner.runChild(iNotesTestSuiteRunner.java:151)
at com.ibm.test.inotes.iNotesTestSuiteRunner$1.evaluate(iNotesTestSuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
at com.ibm.test.inotes.suite.SuiteLauncher.main(SuiteLauncher.java:167)
```

Comment: Can we look into the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running tests in a headless mode, there are no active browser window available. As such your

```
   driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

would always fail in such situations because the driver doesn't know which window to maximise, since there aren't any available.

Try something like this

```
 driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1440, 900));
```

Comment: Thanks ,I use setSize method to replace maximize()

Answer (score 0):

As the error log suggests

```
failed to change window state to normal, current state is maximized
```

I would suggest that in the iNotesTestCase.testSetUp you remove the call maximize before your call to setSize method.

On a side-note I'd also recommend upgrading to the latest chromedriver instalment v2.31 (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

Comment: i have tried chromedriver 2.31 and 2.30, the same error encountered

Comment: @xiaona2016cao try to do what was recommended by other users and edit out the maximize call.

Answer (score 0):

The error stack trace says it all as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to change window state to normal, current state is maximized
```

This error is observed when you try to maximize the Chrome Browser through:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

You can go through the [**GitHub discussion**](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4407) and [**chromedriver issue**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1901) for more details.

IMO, there is no best practice but you can always consider to use the `Options` class to maximize the Chrome Browser window as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```